# Highcharts - Remove gap between tooltip border and content

Tags: highcharts

How can I remove the gap between Highchart's custom tooltip (created from plotoptions > series > tooltip > pointFormatter and useHTML:true) and the html content, **without affecting the tooltip arrow**?

If I set the tooltip borderWidth to 0, it removes the arrow along with the tooltip border.

Please refer to the below picture to see the gap between the tooltip border and the actual content:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer! Simple..

```
tooltip : { 
    ...
    padding : 0
}
```